# Django json serializer with different fields

Tags: json, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have a json
`{{"cosmetics":["perfume1","scent2","cream1"]},{"cosmetics":["perfume2","perfume1","cream2","cream1"]}}`

And a model to which i have to save cosmetics divided in to two fields `cream` and `perfumes`
I have two sets with all the available perfumes and creams as follows

```
PERFUME = {"prefume1", "perfume2", "scent1"}
CREAM = {"cream1", "cream2"}
```

My model is as follows

```
class X(models.Model):
    perfume = ListTextField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20))
    cream = ListTextField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20))
```

My question is, how to write a serializer to match the above model with the given json? (I want to save data from json to db)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't send json as {"PERFUME": [], CREAM:[]}

Comment: nope, should separate the given one 'cosmetics'

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had to edit my model as well as the serializer.
From the serializer I excluded `perfumes` and `cream` fields. Added a `cosmetics` field to the model.
Changed the `save()` method of the model, to set the values for `perfumes` and `cream`

My final code is as follows

```
class X(models.Model):
    perfume = ListTextField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20))
    cream = ListTextField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20))
    cosmetics= ListTextField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=20))
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.perfume= list(set(self.cosmetics) & PERFUMES)
        self.vegetables = list(set(self.cosmetics) & CREAMS)
        super(X, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer.py looks like below

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):  # to save a list field
   child = serializers.CharField()

class XSerializer(serializer.(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cosmetics= StringListField()
    class Meta:
        model = X
        exclude = ("perfume", "cream")
```